# How can I calculate the variance of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, statistics, variance

If I have a list like this:

```
results=[-14.82381293, -0.29423447, -13.56067979, -1.6288903, -0.31632439,
          0.53459687, -1.34069996, -1.61042692, -4.03220519, -0.24332097]
```

I want to calculate the variance of this list in Python which is the average of the squared differences from the mean.

How can I go about this? Accessing the elements in the list to do the computations is confusing me for getting the square differences.

Comment: You do just that. What's the problem?

Comment: @Vincent accessing the elements of the list to get the squared differences

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use numpy's built-in function [`var`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html#numpy.var):

```
import numpy as np

results = [-14.82381293, -0.29423447, -13.56067979, -1.6288903, -0.31632439,
          0.53459687, -1.34069996, -1.61042692, -4.03220519, -0.24332097]

print(np.var(results))
```

This gives you `28.822364260579157`

If - for whatever reason - you cannot use `numpy` and/or you don't want to use a built-in function for it, you can also calculate it "by hand" using e.g. a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
# calculate mean
m = sum(results) / len(results)

# calculate variance using a list comprehension
var_res = sum((xi - m) ** 2 for xi in results) / len(results)
```

which gives you the identical result.

If you are interested in the **standard deviation**, you can use [numpy.std](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.std.html):

```
print(np.std(results))
5.36864640860051
```

[@Serge Ballesta explained very well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35584364/1534017) the difference between variance `n` and `n-1`. In numpy you can easily set this parameter using the option `ddof`; its default is `0`, so for the `n-1` case you can simply do:

```
np.var(results, ddof=1)
```

The "by hand" solution is given in [@Serge Ballesta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35584364/1534017).

Both approaches yield `32.024849178421285`.

You can set the parameter also for `std`:

```
np.std(results, ddof=1)
5.659050201086865
```

Comment: There is an error in this formula: var_res = sum((xi - m) ** 2 for xi in results) / len(results). It should be var_res = sum((xi - m) ** 2 for xi in results) / (len(results) - 1)

Comment: @DanielSilveira: Both expressions are correct; that's what the parameter `ddof` is for (see second half of my answer and the answer I link to).

Answer (score 19):

Starting `Python 3.4`, the standard library comes with the [`variance`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.variance) function (*sample variance* or *variance n-1*) as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html) module:

```
from statistics import variance
# data = [-14.82381293, -0.29423447, -13.56067979, -1.6288903, -0.31632439, 0.53459687, -1.34069996, -1.61042692, -4.03220519, -0.24332097]
variance(data)
# 32.024849178421285
```

The ***p***opulation variance (or *variance n*) can be obtained using the [`pvariance`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.pvariance) function:

```
from statistics import pvariance
# data = [-14.82381293, -0.29423447, -13.56067979, -1.6288903, -0.31632439, 0.53459687, -1.34069996, -1.61042692, -4.03220519, -0.24332097]
pvariance(data)
# 28.822364260579157
```

Also note that if you already know the mean of your list, the `variance` and `pvariance` functions take a second argument (respectively `xbar` and `mu`) in order to spare recomputing the mean of the sample (which is part of the variance computation).

Answer (score 18):

Well, there are two ways for defining the variance. You have the variance *n* that you use when you have a full set, and the variance *n-1* that you use when you have a sample.

The difference between the 2 is whether the value `m = sum(xi) / n` is the real average or whether it is just an approximation of what the average should be.

Example1 : you want to know the average height of the students in a class and its variance : ok, the value `m = sum(xi) / n` is the real average, and the formulas given by Cleb are ok (variance *n*).

Example2 : you want to know the average hour at which a bus passes at the bus stop and its variance. You note the hour for a month, and get 30 values. Here the value `m = sum(xi) / n` is only an approximation of the real average, and that approximation will be more accurate with more values. In that case the best approximation for the actual variance is the variance *n-1*

```
varRes = sum([(xi - m)**2 for xi in results]) / (len(results) -1)
```

Ok, it has nothing to do with Python, but it does have an impact on statistical analysis, and the question is tagged [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) and [variance](/questions/tagged/variance)

Note: ordinarily, statistical libraries like numpy use the variance *n* for what they call `var` or `variance`, and the variance *n-1* for the function that gives the standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is indeed the most elegant and fast way to do it.

I think the actual question was about how to access the individual elements of a list to do such a calculation yourself, so below an example:

```
results=[-14.82381293, -0.29423447, -13.56067979, -1.6288903, -0.31632439,
      0.53459687, -1.34069996, -1.61042692, -4.03220519, -0.24332097]

import numpy as np
print 'numpy variance: ', np.var(results)


# without numpy by hand  

# there are two ways of calculating the variance 
#   - 1. direct as central 2nd order moment (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics))divided by the length of the vector
#   - 2. "mean of square minus square of mean" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)

# calculate mean
n= len(results)
sum=0
for i in range(n):
    sum = sum+ results[i]


mean=sum/n
print 'mean: ', mean

#  calculate the central moment
sum2=0
for i in range(n):
    sum2=sum2+ (results[i]-mean)**2

myvar1=sum2/n
print "my variance1: ", myvar1

# calculate the mean of square minus square of mean
sum3=0
for i in range(n):
    sum3=sum3+ results[i]**2

myvar2 = sum3/n - mean**2
print "my variance2: ", myvar2
```

gives you:

```
numpy variance:  28.8223642606
mean:  -3.731599805
my variance1:  28.8223642606
my variance2:  28.8223642606
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
def get_variance(xs):
    mean = np.mean(xs)
    summed = 0
    for x in xs:
        summed += (x - mean)**2
    return summed / (len(xs))
print(get_variance([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

out 2.0

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
variance = np.var(a, ddof=1)
print(variance)
```

Comment: why is summed divided by (len(xs) - 1) as opposed to just len(xs)?

Answer (score 1):

sometimes all I wanna do it shut my brain off and **COPY PASTE**

```
import math
def get_mean_var(results):
  # calculate mean
  mean = round(sum(results) / len(results), 2)

  # calculate variance using a list comprehension
  var = round(sum((xi - mean) ** 2 for xi in results) / len(results), 2)
  return mean, var
```

**USAGE**

```
get_mean_var([1,3,34])
```

> (12.67, 15.11)

Comment: Variance doesn't need `math.sqrt`. What you give is the standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks @Gqqnbig :D, I removed the sqrt

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use one of the packages like NumPy, but if you want to roll your own, and you want to do incrementally, there is a good algorithm that has higher accuracy. See this link https://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/

I ported my perl implementation to Python. Please point out issues in the comments.

```
Mklast = 0
Mk = 0
Sk = 0
k  = 0 

for xi in results:
  k = k +1
  Mk = Mklast + (xi - Mklast) / k
  Sk = Sk + (xi - Mklast) * ( xi - Mk)
  Mklast = Mk

var = Sk / (k -1)
print var
```

Answer is

```
>>> print var
32.0248491784
```

Comment: That's the sample variance, not the population variance.

Answer (score 0):

Without imports, I would use the following python3 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def createData():
    data1=[12,54,60,3,15,6,36]
    data2=[1,2,3,4,5]
    data3=[100,30000,1567,3467,20000,23457,400,1,15]

    dataset=[]
    dataset.append(data1)
    dataset.append(data2)
    dataset.append(data3)

    return dataset

def calculateMean(data):
    means=[]
    # one list of the nested list
    for oneDataset in data:
        sum=0
        mean=0
        # one datapoint in one inner list
        for number in oneDataset:
            # summing up
            sum+=number
        # mean for one inner list
        mean=sum/len(oneDataset)
        # adding a tuples of the original data and their mean to
        # a list of tuples
        item=(oneDataset, mean)
        means.append(item)

    return means

# to do: substract mean from each element and square the result
# sum up the square results and divide by number of elements
def calculateVariance(meanData):
    variances=[]
    # meanData is the list of tuples
    # pair is one tuple
    for pair in meanData:
        # pair[0] is the original data
        interResult=0
        squareSum=0
        for element in pair[0]:
            interResult=(element-pair[1])**2
            squareSum+=interResult
        variance=squareSum/len(pair[0])
        variances.append((pair[0], pair[1], variance))

    return variances





def main():
    my_data=createData()
    my_means=calculateMean(my_data)
    my_variances=calculateVariance(my_means)
    print(my_variances)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

here you get a print of the original data, their mean and the variance. I know this approach covers a list of several datasets, yet I think you can adapt it quickly for your purpose ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solutions

vac_nums = [0,0,0,0,0,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
2,2,2,2,
3,3,3
]
#your code goes here

```
mean = sum(vac_nums)/len(vac_nums);

count=0;

for i in range(len(vac_nums)):
   variance = (vac_nums[i]-mean)**2;
   count += variance;

print (count/len(vac_nums));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).