# variance of list values

Tags: python, variance

### I want to calculate the variance of values in list x1. Could anyone fix the error in this code?!

```
def my_mean(L):
    s = 0
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        s = s + L[i]
    return s / len(L)
def my_var(L):
    t = 0
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        t = t + L[i] - def my_mean(L) 
    return t*t / len (L)

x1 = [1, 3, 4, -3, 8]
v1 = my_var(x1)
print(v1)
```

Comment: What error? Do you get error messages? Does it give wrong results? If so, what's the input, expected output and the actual output?

Comment: You should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I need to use variance equation to solve  value in x1 list. could you recommend any modification of the code?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `def` keyword only when you define the function.

When you call to the function you don't need to use `def` again.

Fix this row:

```
t = t + L[i] - def my_mean(L)
```

To:

```
t = t + L[i] - my_mean(L)
```

Comment: it still has a problem but now it gives a result as below but I need to establish variance equation in my code. can you recommend any modification?!
3.944304526105059e-32
0.0

Comment: @HeroHamada, try read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583302/how-can-i-calculate-the-variance-of-a-list-in-python).. you can assist the numpy lib.

Comment: I think I am getting closer but still not work
def my_var(L):
    s = 0
    t = 0
    u = 0
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        s += L[i]
        t = s/len(L)
        u = (L[i]-t)*(L[i]-t)
    return u / len(L)
x1 = [1, 3, 4, -3, 8]
x2 = [1, -4, 7, 2]
v1 = my_var(x1)
v2 = my_var(x2)
print(v1)
print(v2)