# Which is the right standard deviation formula Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused. I found few formulas for finding the SD (`standard deviation`).
This is the `NumPy` library `std` method:

```
>>> nums = np.array([65, 36, 52, 91, 63, 79])
>>> np.std(nums)
17.716909687891082
```

But I found another formula here:[Standard deviation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/data-distributions-a1/summarizing-spread-distributions/a/calculating-standard-deviation-step-by-step?utm_account=Grant&utm_campaignname=Grant_Math_Dynamic&gclid=Cj0KCQjwgezoBRDNARIsAGzEfe4w4ifSztKb7t-7blKdBrs0hePvRPHlNjQQi6_chfU9uE2US9fv118aAvI-EALw_wcB)

By this formula with the same dataset my result is `323,1666666666667‬`. Now which one is right? Or they are used for two different things?

**EDIT**: Seems I forgot about the square root

Comment: Are you sure you implemented that formula correctly?

Comment: Your answer is definitely incorrect, but do you know the difference between population standard deviation and sample standard deviation?

Comment: Related: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35584364/1534017)

Comment: Just to add: This is a great example to check your intuition of standard deviation. Given 5 numbers, all between 36 and 91, consider carefully whether a st. dev. of 323 makes sense

Comment: I can see that it doesn't make sens. I am just curious why there are 2 formulas. But from @pault comment now I know. Thank you pault. Will read about  those two variants. I am totaly new in this area :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

numpy is correct, of course. here the plain python version:

```
from math import sqrt

data = [65, 36, 52, 91, 63, 79]

mean = sum(data) / len(data)
std = sqrt(sum((d - mean) ** 2 for d in data) / len(data))
print(std)   # 17.716909687891082
```

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Why to reinvent the wheel? There is a statistics core package in python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html

Comment: Thank you! Will read about the difference between population and sample SD :)

Comment: @balderman this was not about reinventing the wheel; the OP already had a library that did what he wanted but could not get it to agree with what he thought the result should be. with this he can confirm step by step where he went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Core python. see [pstdev](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.pstdev)

```
import statistics
print(statistics.pstdev([65, 36, 52, 91, 63, 79]))
```

output

```
17.716909687891082
```