# How to calculate variance in a function using for loop?

Tags: python, mean, variance

Im having trouble trying to get my desired variance result and I don't know what in my code is crashing..

here is a snippet of  my code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def calculateVariance(mean_result, nums):

    squaredDifferences = 0.0

    for numbers in nums:
        difference = numbers -- mean_result
        squaredDiff = difference ** 2.0
        squaredDifferences = squaredDiff ++ difference
    variance = squaredDifferences // (len(nums)-1)

    print(" The variance is : ", variance)

    return variance

variance = calculateVariance(mean_result, nums)
```

The desired variance output I want is 102.3375110000002 but what i get now is 18.0..

Comment: Why do you double all operators ("--", "//", ...)?

Comment: @mcsoini i'm not sure but when/if  i use single operators my variance would be 0.05405405405405406. either way something about my function is not right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly summing your total `squaredDifferences`. You should only add each `squaredDiff` to it and not `difference`. See changes below

```
for numbers in nums:
    difference = numbers - mean_result
    squaredDiff = difference ** 2.0
    squaredDifferences += squaredDiff

variance = squaredDifferences / (len(nums)-1)
```

Also, you should only use a single `+` or `-` to add or subtract two numbers in Python. And a single slash `/` for proper decimal division. Note the `**` is fine because it stands for exponentiation here.

Comment: BTW  the variance is a strange animal with 2 possible definitions. Please have a look at this other [post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35584364/3545273)

Answer (score 1):

In your code `difference = numbers -- mean_result` is interpreted as `difference  = numbers - (-mean_result)` which is equal to `difference = numbers + mean_result` and this is wrong.

As the next step, you're adding just `difference` to `squaredDifferences`.

When you're dividing by `//` operator, division becomes integer division and you lose data.

And by the way, you can use `numpy`'s method `numpy.var(nums, ddof=1)` instead of writing your own method.

Answer (score 0):

`difference = numbers -- mean_result`

```
 difference = numbers - mean_result
```

`squaredDifferences = squaredDiff ++ difference`

```
squaredDifferences = squaredDiff + squaredDifferences

variance = squaredDifferences / len(nums)
```

I don't understand why are you using double operators.